# How to overlay a cq widget so it is also available in SiteAdmin

Tags: aem

The `CQ.tagging.TagInputField` provided two configuration parameter which won't work in combination:

- tagsBasePath
- namespaces

Using the OOTB facebook tags as example, I want to restric the dialog to only display the Favorite Teams. The Structure is this:

[image: Facebook Tags]

So I set tagBasePath to `/etc/tags/facebook` and namespaces to `[favorite_teams]`. This does what it is supposed to do and only shows the two teams in the dialog. But when you click on it, a JavaScript exceptions is thrown. The problem lies in the following method defined in `/libs/cq/tagging/widgets/source/CQ.tagging.js`

```
CQ.tagging.parseTag = function(tag, isPath) {
    var tagInfo = {
        namespace: null,
        local: tag,
        getTagID: function() {
            return this.namespace + ":" + this.local;
        }
    };

    // parse tag pattern: namespace:local
    var colonPos = tag.indexOf(isPath ? '/' : ':');
    if (colonPos > 0) {
        // the first colon ":" delimits a namespace
        // don't forget to trim the strings (in case of title paths)
        tagInfo.namespace = tag.substring(0, colonPos).trim();
        tagInfo.local = tag.substring(colonPos + 1).trim();
    }

    return tagInfo;
};
```

It does not respect the configurations set on the widget and returns a tagInfo where the namespace is null. I then overlayed the method in my authoring JavaScripts, but this is of course not working in the SiteAdmin as my custom JS are not included.

So, do I really have to overwrite the CQ.tagging.js below libs or can I somehow inject my overlay into the SiteAdmin so the PageProperties Dialog opened from there works as well?

UPDATE: I had a chat with Adobe support regarding this and it was pointed out that if you use `tagsBasePath` you need to place it somewhere else than below `/etc/tags`. But this won't work as well as the `TagListServlet` will return no tags as `/etc/tags` is also fixed in the TagManager as the `tagsBasePath`. I now overwrite the above mentioned js at its location, being well aware that I need to check it if we install a hotfix or an update. Is someone has a more elegant solution I'd be still thankful.

Comment: I am also trying to overlay libs KeyPlugin.js /libs/cq/ui/rte/core/plugins/KeyPlugin.js   , could you please let me know, if you have any idea on this. Thank you.

Comment: @Sri what exactly are you trying to achieve? Maybe it would be better if you just create a question for it and maybe I can give some pointers. The comments aren't the right place for this.